# Why doesn't Math.Round return an int?

Tags: c#, math

In C#, why don't the rounding math functions Floor, Ceiling and Round return an `int`? Considering the result of the function will always be an integer, why does it return a `float`, `double` or `decimal`?

Comment: Round is overloaded, and the return types have to match for starters ;p

Comment: Imagine you call `Math.Round(1E30)` and it returns an `int`, what will happen?

Comment: So you're saying it's the BCL's job to determine what you want the result to be?

Comment: It makes sense for `Math.Round()` to return the same type as its argument.  A better question would be why there aren't functions for `Math.RoundToInt32` or `Math.RoundToInt64`, `Math.FloorToInt32`, and `Math.FloorToInt64`.

Comment: Performance and stability.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[`double` has the range of ±5.0 × 10<sup>−324</sup> to ±1.7 × 10<sup>308</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) and [`long` has the range of –9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx). Unfortunately not **all** integral floating point values can be represented by an integer.

For example, `1e19` has already exceeded the range of a 64-bit signed integer.

```
(long)Math.Round(1e19) == -9223372036854775808L // WTF?
```

While it is true that the single-argument overloads `Math.Round(double)` and `Math.Round(decimal)` will always return an integral value, these overloads still cannot return an integer value type.

If you *know* that the value passed to the function will return a value representable by an integer value type, you can cast it yourself. The library won't do that because it needs to consider the general case.

Comment: Note, however, that there are long integers which are *not* representable as doubles: `(double)100000000000000001L == 1e17` (and `1e17 == 1e17+1`).

Comment: @AntalS-Z yep. For greater preceision, using [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75(v=vs.80).aspx) type is better.

Answer (score 13):

> Considering the result of the function will always be an integer,

No it won't be. You can even specify number of digits with [Math.Round Method (Double, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby.aspx)

> digits Type: 
>   System.Int32 
>   The number of fractional digits in the return value.

Comment: +1 Indeed, since not all times we need to round to an int

Comment: I can't help but be dumb here, the documentation for Round says "returns the integer nearest a" - and you're saying it doesn't always return an integer. This doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: @PandaWood, where do you see "returns the integer nearest" ? I couldn't find it, could you please share the link. If you are referring to this `The integer nearest a. If the fractional component of a is halfway between two integers, one of which is even and the other odd, then the even number is returned. Note that this method returns a Double instead of an integral type.` then note the last part.

Comment: @Habib Right, thanks, I didn't see the last part for some reason

Answer (score 3):

This is done to include numbers larger than what are included in the range of an int.
So Math.Floor will return a double which could be casted to int or long based on the size and developer.
If you tried Math.Floor outside range of int, it'd have failed if Math.Floor returned an int, but it doesn't, it returns a double which you can cast to long.

```
     double d = 4147483647.5678;
     long a = (long)Math.Floor(d);
     int b = (int)Math.Floor(d);
     Console.WriteLine(a);
     Console.WriteLine(b);
```

Note that on casting to int, b was  pushed back to MIN int, since int can't accomodate it.